# How can I test methods where I need a file?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have the class "Password". In this class I have got two public methods, "setPassword" and "getPassword"
Here is the code:

```
public static void setPassword(String password) throws IOException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("password", password);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("data/password/" + User.getCurrentUser() + "_password.json");
    fileWriter.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
    fileWriter.close();
}

public static String getPassword(String user) throws IOException, ParseException {

    File passwordFile = new File("data/password/" + user.toLowerCase() + "_password.json");

    return readPassword(passwordFile);
}

private static String readPassword(File passwordFile) throws IOException, ParseException {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(passwordFile);
    Object object = jsonParser.parse(fileReader);

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
    fileReader.close();

    return (String) jsonObject.get("password");
}
```

How can I test this methods with JUnit?
Should I use the Mockito-Framework?

Comment: the JavaFX and Mockito tags probably have nothing to do with the question

Comment: I deleted the tags

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking things, I would redesign the class to make it testable:

- pass the file name in a constructor
- make the methods non static

In your test, you can now [create a temporary file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) and use it for your tests.

Comment: Why should I make it non static?

Comment: if you pass the file name to the constructor, you need an instance method to access it.

Comment: why I need a constructor?

Comment: haha, there are one hundred thousand why here. interesting. I'd like to see how does @assylias  answer the OP's questions infinitely.

Comment: Can you give an example @assilias

Answer (score 0):

I played with your example and found a solution based on [PowerMock](http://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock).

I simplified your class as much as possible to show only the key aspect of workaround: you extract the getting of password file to a package visible method and then in tests you mock this method:

```
public class Password {
    public static String getPassword(String user) throws IOException {
        File passwordFile = getPasswordFile(user);
        return readPassword(passwordFile);
    }

    public static void setPassword(String password) throws IOException {
        File passwordFile = getPasswordFile("User.getCurrentUser()");
        writePassword(passwordFile, password);
    }

    static File getPasswordFile(String userName) {
        return new File("data/password/" + userName.toLowerCase() + "_password.json");
    }

    private static String readPassword(File passwordFile) throws IOException {
        // do the reading
        return "actual password";
    }

    private static void writePassword(File passwordFile, String password) {
        // do the saving
    }
}
```

---

In the test you partially mock your Password class by spy() call and substitute the password file by your expected one:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.your.domain.Password")
public class PasswordTest {
    @Test
    public void getPassword() throws Exception {
        spy(Password.class);

        final File expectedPasswordFile = new File("some test specific path");
        when(Password.getPasswordFile("bob")).thenReturn(expectedPasswordFile);

        final String actualResult = Password.getPassword("bob");
        Assert.assertEquals("expected result", actualResult);
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of such way: your getPasswordFile() is not covered by unit tests.

May be I missed some your project specific details but I hope the idea is clear for you.

Comment: I will try it out.